# how to use same route url for multiple action in slim framework

Tags: php, slim

I am creating the API using slim framework. I faced the following problem.
I use one of the routes for given input.That is, json input: `{ "tagname": "tname"}`. Route is

```
$app->post('/tag',function () use($app, $db){
    //code
});
```

Now, I want to use the same route for another input.json: `[{"tid": "1"},{"tid": "2"}]`. Route is

```
$app->post('/tag',function () use($app, $db){
    //code
});
```

How do solve it?

Comment: Separate your rerquests to GET and POST.

Comment: @bub that is incorrect.  HTTP specifications say that [GET should be safe](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-9.1.1), i.e. should not have the effect of modifying data.  Unless OP is trying to retrieve data in one of these cases and submit data in the other, using different HTTP verbs is not the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

Slim's router can't call different functions for same path based on received content.

In your particular case the simplest way to deal with two different types of input data on one route would be something like this (I assume you are getting data as POST body with `application/json` which is not processed by Slim2)

```
$app->post('/tag',function () use($app, $db){
   $payload = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
   if(is_array($payload)) {
       // code to deal with [{"tid": "1"},{"tid": "2"}] 
   } else {
       // code to deal with { "tagname": "tname"} 
   }
});
```

But even easier and logically would be make `/tag` route for single and `/tags` for multiple. Or just require to send all tags as array - even single one.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass extra parameter to perform another action in same route and separate your code with if condition